# Google Maps: How to get json data of path between two points with google maps api

Tags: json, api, google-maps

I am trying to get json data of path between two points.
How can i do this with google maps api ?

Like for a given set of latitude/longitude pairs(e.g A={12,43},B={978,54}) i want the output as

`path = [A,{12,3},{123,32},B]`

How can i do this ?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)?

Answer (score 0):

The [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) will give you a lot of data such as the polyline and points between two given locations

Comment: Please can be more specific about which api should i use(in the directions api itself) ?

Comment: There's a sample request here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start